# Bug when swiping from view with uinavigationbar to one without

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I have an application with 2 viewcontrollers, ViewController and NextViewController. ViewController does not have a navigation bar and has a white status bar. NextViewController does have a navigation bar and has a black (default) status bar. I have encountered a bug when swiping back to ViewController from NextViewController and cancelling the swipe where the navigation bar on NextViewController will disappear. The storyboard simply has the two views with a button and an action segue. The bug does not always happen, but often enough to be a problem. The bug has to do with the method `- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle`, as everything works fine when I remove the methods.

Can I somehow stop this bug from happening while still having a white status bar on my ViewController and having the swipe enabled or am I forced to remove either functionality?

ViewController

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

NextViewController

```
@implementation NextViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

Other possibly relevant info: Experiencing the issue on an iPhone 5s with iOS 8, but it also happens on the simulator with iOS 9. View controller-based status bar appearance is set to the default, YES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Status bar style depends on `- preferredStatusBarStyle` of the view controller if the navigation bar is hidden, otherwise of the navigation controller, so the `- preferredStatusBarStyle` in your `NextViewController` is useless.

It seems that the bug is related with the status bar style of the navigation controller, you can subclass `UINavigationController` override the method [childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle) to avoid the bug.

```
@implementation MyNavigationController

- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle {
    return self.topViewController;
}

@end
```

Now the status bar style will depend on the view controller no matter whether the navaigation bar is hidden or not. And the bug would not happend.