# Overwrite 'preferredStatusBarStyle' method makes navigationBar hidden strange

Tags: ios, navigationbar, uistatusbar

All my viewcontroller inherit my BaseViewController, when I overwirte'preferredStatusBarStyle' method in my BaseViewController, navigationbar hidden works strange. here is the gif
[image]

But if I delete the 'preferredStatusBarStyle' method , it works fine

[image]

And if  I overwrite this method in my subclassViewController, it works fine too.Did I should overwrite this method in all my SubclassViewController?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33030309/5311459 this answer worked for me.you can have a try.